# How can you measure page to page speed on a website?

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

There are many tools to measure page load speed [GT Metrix](https://gtmetrix.com), [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com), [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org) and all of [Google's tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

However these all measure the page load speed of a single page in isolation. How do I measure the page to page speed of a site?

Answer (score 0):

Well, each tool is accurate on its own way.

For example Pingdom / GTMetrix allows you to measure the speed of your website when using a Computer with leased internet line.

If you want to measure the speed of your whole website, you need to categorize your pages using templates and then calculate yourself the amount of time between **First Byte Received** + **DomContentLoaded**.

Then as soon as this is ready you need to send it towards an analytics tool (maybe Google Analytics) and measure it out of your user experience.